# Which sentence is correct?

Tags: sentence-meaning, singular-vs-plural

**Is it give or gives?**

“Looking back at these outros give me life.”

“Looking back at these outros gives me life.”

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the verb is the gerund phrase *looking back*, which is construed as singular. It requires the verb *gives*. Don't be confused by the nearness of the plural noun *outros*.